# How to createNLP( natrual language processing domain language) model.....?

Tags: nlp

how to design create NLP domain language model or grammar file 
any data structure please let me know

```
        <one-of>
           <item>
               <tag>fruits="Apple"<tag/>
                 <one-of>
                      <item>
                           <token>Apple</token>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                           <token>i want Apple</token>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                           <token>i want to order an apple</token>
                      </item>                               
                 </one-of>
            </item>
        </one-of>
</rule>
```